# Detect when image (or any type of file) is accessed from site and notify via email

Tags: php, html, image, email, tracking

I plan on adding a logo image to an email newsletter and use it as a tracking image.  This image will be hosted on my site (eg. `my_logo.gif`) and referenced in the html of the email (eq. `<img src="http://www.example.com/my_logo.gif" />`).  I would like to create a script in php that emails me when that image is accessed/viewed.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

All ideas and suggestions to complete this are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put something like this in an `.htaccess` file in the image directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+\.jpg)$ image.php?image=$1 [nocase]
```

Put something like this into a file `image.php` in the same directory:

```
// send email here

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($_GET['image']);
```

This is only a simple example, make sure you **validate** the `$_GET['image']` variable to make sure it's an image in the same directory, otherwise someone might be able to abuse this script to read files in other directories (`image.php?image=../../../passwords`).

Comment: Great solution.  I now have a question after implementing it... Can my validation be strictly the addition of this line in my .htaccess file: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
or do I still need the validation in the image.php file.  If the answer is the latter, how do you suggest I do this?

Comment: @Serv **Always** confirm all paths! Anybody could simply invoke the `image.php` file directly, circumventing your RewriteCond entirely. I'm sure you can find solutions for validating the path on SO, but using [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) and checking if the beginning of the path matches the image directory (`substr($path, 0, 13) == '/foo/bar/img/'`) basically does it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Display image
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg('my_logo.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);

//logging or notifying stuff here
// ...
```

and just link to this script like `<img src="script.php" />`

Comment: If you're going to read a jpeg and output the same jpeg you can skip the long way around the gd functions and just dump the file as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the request to an .jpg file via .htaccess and count it etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `readfile()` function and sending the proper content-type headers. You can execute other program code before or after the image is sent to the browser.

If the following program code has a long execution time, you will want to look into the [output control](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions.

Answer (score -1):

It would probably be easier to link to the php file and have that forward or present the image itself AND count/track/email you whenever the php file is accessed.